# How do I loop php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is my `product` array -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Product1'
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 'Product2'
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 'Product3'
            [8] => 'Product4'
            [9] => 'Product5'
        )
)
```

And this is the `category` array for the product -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'cat1'
            [1] => 'cat2'
            [2] => 'cat3'
            [3] => 'cat4'
            [4] => 'cat5'
            [5] => 'cat6'
            [6] => 'cat7'
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
        )
)
```

Final output to be require in this format -

```
Array
(
'Product1' => Array(
           [0] => 'cat1',
           [1] => 'cat2',
           [2] => 'cat1',
           [3] => 'cat4'
           ),
'Product2' => Array(
           [0] => 'cat5',
           [1] => 'cat6',
           [2] => 'cat7'
           ),
'Product3' => Array(
           [0] => 'No Cat'
           ),
'Product4' => Array(
           [0] => 'No Cat'
           ),
'Product5' => Array(
           [0] => 'No Cat',
           )
)
```

I tried this but this is not forming the correct output --

```
$newarr = array();
foreach( $productData[0] as $arr1 )
{

    if( $arr1 != '' )
    {
        foreach( $catData[0] as $catnames ){
        $newarr[$arr1] = array($compnames);
        }
    }

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: how the merge should be done? what's the logic behind it?

Comment: How did you end up with these arrays?

Comment: try this $newarr[$arr1][] = $compnames;

Comment: @Dasun Logic is the- Product array iterates over the category array and fill category till next product name meet..if it is crate a key and iterates angain

Comment: @Praveenkalal it is filling all categories at all product names

Comment: Is this data pulled from a db?  This is a crazy situation to be in. I just want to live.

Comment: @shapeshifter data is from Excel read..so it is in this strange format

Comment: @shapeshifter you dont need to take panic if you cant

Comment: Will you always have the same number of elements in teh product and category arrays?

Comment: @shapeshifter format will be the same only thing that changes is the number of products and categories

Comment: Ok, I have a solution.  I depends on a couple of things being consistent though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If count($productData[0]) == count($catData[0]) you can use a for loop.
If $productData[0][0] is always going to contain a product name then this should work.

```
<?php
// array to return
$a = array();
// loop thru array
for($i = 0; $i < count($productData[0]); $i++) {
  // if the product name exists its time to start a new array entry
  if($productData[0][$i] != '') {
    // get the product name as we need might need this for the next iteration
    $current = $productData[0][$i];
    // create the new array
    $a[$current] = array();

    if($catData[0][$i] != '') {
      // and save the category at this iteration into the new array
      $a[$current][] = $catData[0][$i];
    } else {
      $a[$current][] = 'No Cat';
    }
  } else {
    // product name was blank, and $current should be set, append the category.
    $a[$current][] = $catData[0][$i];
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: yes first will always contain a name..thx a lot +1 and green tick :)

Comment: No problem!  I just realised I didn't handle "No Cat".

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..

```
$newarr = array();
foreach( $productData[0] as $key => $product )
{

    if( $product != '' )
    {
        $newarr[$product] = array();
        $currentProduct = $product;

    }

    if( isset($catData[0][$key]) && ($catData[0][$key] != '') )
    {
        $newarr[$currentProduct][] = $catData[0][$key];
    }
    else
    {
         $newarr[$currentProduct][] = 'No Cat';
    }

}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: Thx bro for another solution +1 :)

Comment: This solution will also handle 'NO Cat'. :)

Comment: Should be $newarr[$currentProduct][] = $catData[0][$key];

Comment: Also note isset('') will return true.  If you are importing empty fields from excel they may be empty strings not null or false.